# Fetch specific array from multidimensional array with matching value php

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I have 2 arrays -

```
$array1 =
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [like_status] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 3
            [like_status] => 1
        )

)

$array2 = 

Array
(
    [isLoggedIn] => 1
    [userId] => 3
)
```

My requirement is I want to fetch the array where userId = 3. There can be multiple records in `$array1` But I only want to fetch the array which have userID = 3, which is in $array2

I am able to get into the condition and match but not able to fetch.

```
if(array_search($array2['userId'], array_column($array1, 'user_id')) !== False) {
                                print_r($array1);
                            }
```

But it should only return the specific array.

Comment: Is the `user_id` unique in `$array1`, or can there be many children with the same `user_id`?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Yes It will be unique

Comment: You can't answer that question with yes or no. It's a double question

Comment: My bad, I think the comment was edited later on ;)

Comment: Didnt you ask this question once already today

Comment: @RiggsFolly That question was different I deleted that question without anyone answered because I got the solution myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to create a flat array of the userid and use array_intersect to get the matching full arrays.

```
$userids = array_column($array1, "user_id");
$matching = array_intersect_key($array1, array_intersect($userids, [$array2['user_id']]));
```

Now $matching will be all the `$array1` subarrays where userid is matching `$array2['userId']`.

Comment: @LAW No problem. Just for full disclosure, I wrote this answer before you answered the comment that it's unique items in the array. If I had known it was unique I would not have answered like this. I'm quite sure this method is slower than Jim's answer. And I advice you to go with his answer since it is unique. This method however may be useful at some other point, but not for this issue if I'm honest.

Comment: Heh. I actually prefer your answer Andreas as it's neater.

Comment: @Jim I guess it's a preference thing then. But I still believe your code is faster

Answer (score 3):

```
array_search($array2['userId'], array_column($array1, 'user_id'))
```

Will return the index of a matching item or `false` if there is no matching item. You can use this info to grab the array from `$array1`.

I.e.

```
$index = array_search($array2['userId'], array_column($array1, 'user_id')) !== False);
if($index !== false){
    print_r($array1[$index]);
}
```

Note that this assumes that there is only one matching user id in the array - if there are more only the first will be found.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using **foreach** also, if you want to like below

```
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if($value['user_id'] == $array2['userId'])
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($value);echo '</pre>';
        break;
    }
}
```

Output :

> Array (
>       [user_id] => 3
>       [like_status] => 1 )

Comment: Use `echo '<pre>' . print_r($value, true) . '</pre>';`easier to read

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using foreach loop

```
foreach( $array1 as $val ){
  $val['user_id'] == $array2['userId'] ? $result[] = $val : ''; 
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r( $result );
```